# How do I convert from CSpDynamicString to `char *` with ATL?

Tags: atl, text-to-speech, sapi

I'm writing a custom text-to-speech program that uses SAPI 5, and one problem I'm facing is that enumerating voices with `SpEnumTokens` and iterating over them produces `CSpDynamicString` objects.

My question is, how do I convert `CSpDynamicString` to `char *` so I could `printf` them?

It looks like I've to use some kind of text-conversion macro from ATL. I found an example that does this (given `dstrDesc` is `CSpDynamicString`):

```
CSpDynamicString dstrDesc;
SpGetDescription(voiceToken, &dstrDesc);

USES_CONVERSION;

printf("%s\n", W2T(dstrDesc));
```

However this only prints the first character of the voice name!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CSpDynamicString` implements an operator to convert to `WCHAR*` and also manages the `LPWSTR` pointer internally. So, `W2T` gets you `LPTSTR` pointer as `printf` argument. If you have a Unicode build, this is results still in a `WCHAR*` pointer and `printf("%s"...` expects `CHAR*` argument - this is where you can have the problem you are describing.

Try it this way:

```
CSpDynamicString dstrDesc;
SpGetDescription(voiceToken, &dstrDesc);
printf("%ls\n", (WCHAR*) dstrDesc);
```